# How to copy data of all columns of a row to another table except primary key column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql table called **table1** and **table2** both having product_id as primary key with auto increment. I need to copy some of rows from table1 to table2 **without copying** product_id column value. Since I have 20+ columns in a single table I don't want to use it like

```
INSERT INTO table2('col1','col2'.....)
SELECT ('col1','col2'.....) FROM table1
WHERE product_id = 1;
```

Is there any way that I can use to copy data like below

```
INSERT INTO table2('product_id',*)
SELECT * FROM table2
WHERE product_id = 1;
```

Or any alternative methods ?
thank you

Comment: No such syntax, list needed columns one-by-one, in SELECT at least. `INSERT INTO table2 SELECT NULL, col1, col2, .. FROM table1` - NULL will cause new value generation for autoincremented primary key column. PS. There is a lot of syntax errors in your SQL code - incorrect quote chars, incorrect excess parenthesis...

Comment: @Akina Thanks for the response. I just wrote it for demonstration purpose only. thanks for pointing me about the Errors.